# can es6 class have public properties as well as functions?

Tags: javascript, class, properties, public, ecmascript-6

All the examples of classes I see are

```
class myClass{
    constructor(){}
    someFunction(){}
```

what I want to add is

```
    someObject {myvalue:value}
}
```

this doesn't seem to compile.  An old fashioned object would be

```
{
    somefunction: function(){}
    someProperty:  {myvalue:value}
}
```

is this not possible in es6 classes?

Comment: Why do you want the value to be stored on the prototype?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd need to put it inside your constructor:

```
class myClass{
    constructor(){
        this.someObject = { myvalue:value };
    }
}
var obj = new myClass();
console.log(obj.someObject.myvalue); // value
```

If required, you can add the object onto the prototype chain the same as you would in ES5:

```
class myClass{
    constructor(){

    }
}
myClass.prototype.someObject = { myvalue:value };
var obj = new myClass();
console.log(obj.someObject.myvalue); // value
```

Note that there is no such thing as *real* private properties on a class. Any variable you attach to a class is public.

There is a Stage 0 proposal for [Class Properties in ES7](https://gist.github.com/jeffmo/054df782c05639da2adb). If using Babel, this can be enabled using Experimental mode, allowing the following:

```
class MyClass {
  myProp = {value: "one"};
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.myProp);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, but I really want it both on the prototype and in the class declaration.  Is that possible?

Comment: Currently, you can add onto the prototype the same as in ES5: `myClass.prototype.someObject = { ... };`. If you are using Babel, it allows for [ES7 Class Properties](https://gist.github.com/jeffmo/054df782c05639da2adb) in experimental mode

Comment: I have to say this is an almost ridiculous omission in the class spec. I mean what sort of idiot designs a class that only has functions?  If you only want functions you don't even need a damn class.  Very frustrating situation.  Anyway, thanks for pointing me to the es7 babel solution.

Comment: Ok, after reading the babel docs about class properties it does seems to be somewhat problematic. Resulting from the prototypal inheritance that js uses. Which is perhaps one reason that there never was and shouldn't be a class structure in js because it leads one to believe that this class will behave similarly to a class in almost any other language, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy way to simulate properties: getters.

```
var obj = {myvalue:value};

class Foo {
    get someProperty() {
       return obj;
    }
}
```

Whether it makes sense to use it entirely depends on the use case.

Comment: Yes thank you.  I'm aiming for something elegant as a pattern for my domain.  And by elegant I mean simple without a lot of necessary procedural knowledge. I don't think the class syntactical sugar is going to work.  But I may find a way. So my object is going to be a collection of functions.  I don't want to have it nested any deeper than necessary.

Comment: Heh, I forgot about ES5 getters - this is much cleaner than using prototype which is non-obvious in ES6.